# Print CSS: Empty white space at top

Tags: css, printing, html-table

Struggling with what seems to be a common problem, but none of the suggestions I've found so far is working. I'm working on a stylesheet for printing, the page contains nothing more then a table and one h1 tag.

The problem is that I'm getting empty white space at the top of the page, about 1/4 of the page in portrait and half the page in landscape - neither is obviously not acceptable for my users.

I've tried zeroing margins on every possible element I can think off, including *body, html, table, tr and tr.* Pasting the HTML and CSS below (some tags is for other HTML not found below, these are for other pages also using the same CSS for print), hopefully it's a simple fix or missing margin :)

```
/*Print CSS template */
body, #content, #container {
   width: 100%;
   margin: 0;
   float: none;
   background: #fff url(none);
}

#topnav, #navbar, #nav, #sidebar, .ad, .noprint {
   display: none; 
}
body {
   font: 1em Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
   color: #000; 
}

h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6 {
   font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
   color: #000;
}
h1 { font-size: 250%; }
h2 { font-size: 175%; }

a:link, a:visited {
   color: #00c;
   font-weight: bold;
   text-decoration: underline; }
#content a:link:after, #content a:visited:after {
   content: " (" attr(href) ") ";
}

/*Print CSS template END */

.r_main
{
    width: auto;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;

}

table{
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
}

.r_wrap
{
    margin: 0;
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
    min-height: 30px;
    float: left;
    display: block;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
}

.r_left 
{
    margin: 0;
    width: 300px;
    color: #000;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    font: 13px Arial, Helvetica,"Lucida Grande", serif; color: #000;
}

.r_right
{
    margin: 0;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    color: #000;
    font: 13px Arial, Helvetica,"Lucida Grande", serif; color: #000;
}

.r_right p
{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 7px 0 3px 0;
    font: 13px Arial, Helvetica,"Lucida Grande", serif; color: #000;
}

.r_left span, .r_right span
{
    display: block;

    margin: 0;
    padding: 5px 0 0 0;
}

.r_right ul 
{

    margin: 3px 0 0 15px;
    padding: 0;
}

.r_right ul li
{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 3px 0 0 0;
}

.r_zeb1
{
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
}

.r_zeb2
{
    background-color: #e9e9e9;    
}
```

**HTML**

```
<table>
<tr class="r_wrap r_zeb2">                               
<td class="r_left"><span>Location</span></td>
<td class="r_right"><span>'.$frm->get_location($selectedE['e_location']).'</span></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Fix your html please, i don't think all those `'` can pass through the w3c validator.

Comment: The ' are left overs from PHP echo. But, I'll remove them :)

Comment: If you go to another computer, are you seeing the same problem?

Comment: I'm not seeing the problem you're describing here (using Firefox, IE9 and Chrome): http://jfcoder.com/test/printcss.html

Comment: I'm thinking you've selected in your printer setup settings something that centers vertically. Check your printer settings in the browser.

Comment: Embarrassing, the problem seems to be localized to my computer and only Firefox. Was so sure this was a global problem that I didn't check it on another computer or browser. Thank you all for replies :)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the h1 is before the table, it could be the issue. You might want to zero the margins & padding on it. It could also help to switch to 'pt' for your font-size instead of using a %.

```
h1{
   margin:0;
   padding:0;
   font-size: 36pt;
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

Agree with user401183, I think its the font size

```
h1 { font-size: 250%; }
h2 { font-size: 175%; }
```